# Save an enum in RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, enums, randomaccessfile

Ok, I have a class called `Encuadernacion.java`

```
public enum Encuadernacion {
    NONE("Ninguno"),
    RUSTICA("Rustica"),
    CARTONE("Cartone"),
    PIEL("Piel"),
    ESPIRAL("Espiral"),
    GRAPADA("Grapada");

    private final String ENCUADERNAR;

    Encuadernacion(String descripcion){
        this.ENCUADERNAR = descripcion;
    }
    public String getDescripcion(){
        return ENCUADERNAR;
    }
}
```

and then the book creation called `Libro.java`

```
public class Libro implements Serializable{
    private Encuadernacion encuadernado;
    public void setEncuadernado(int encuadernar){
        this.encuadernado = Encuadernacion.values()[encuadernar];
        //this encuadernar index is handled on another class.
    }
    public String getEncuadernacion(){
        return encuadernado.getDescripcion();
     }
        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return encuadernado.getDescripcion();
        }
```

and then the main class named `Test.java`

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
        RandomAccessFile fichero = null;
        try {
                fichero = new RandomAccessFile("BIBLIO.DAT", "rw");

        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.printf("Mensaje: %s", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I write the enum into `BIBLIO.DAT`, it gets written as a string, It's Ok until this step. But when I want to read it, I create a new book while read those words. 
`Listar.java`

```
    public class Listar {
        public static void lista(RandomAccessFile fichero)throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{    
            try{
                while(true){
                    Libro libro=new Libro();
                    libro.setEncuadernado(fichero.readUTF());
                    System.out.println(libro.toString());
                }
        }catch(EOFException e){
            if(fichero!=null) fichero.close();
        }
    }
}
```

In this `libro.setEncuadernado(fichero.readUTF());` This is not possible because this has to be a value from `Encuadernacion SOMETHING;` 
How can I solve that? Transforming this string into enum value, or writing in diferent way the enum into `BIBLIO.DAT`, but `RandomAccessFile` has not a method to do that.

the code is cut for better reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved like this.

```
public static String listarEncuadernados(){
        Scanner scann=new Scanner(System.in);
        int i =0;
        for (Encuadernacion tipos: Encuadernacion.values()){
            System.out.printf("\n%d.- %s", i, tipos.getDescripcion());
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println();

        int op = scann.nextInt();
        return Encuadernacion.values()[op].getDescripcion();
    }


public class Libro implements Serializable{
    public void setEncuadernado(String encuadernar){
            this.encuadernado = Encuadernacion.valueOf(encuadernar.toUpperCase());

    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return encuadernado.getDescripcion();
    }
}

public class Listar {
    public static void lista(RandomAccessFile fichero)throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{

        try{
            while(true){
                Libro libro=new Libro();
                libro.setEncuadernado(fichero.readUTF());
                System.out.println(libro.toString());
        }
       }catch(EOFException e){
        if(fichero!=null) fichero.close();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think it is worth to try:

```
public void setEncuadernado(String encuadernar){
    this.encuadernado = Encuadernacion.valueOf(encuadernar);
    //this encuadernar index is handled on another class.
}
```

in a Libro class. But as your code is not a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I didn't test it.

Comment: this answer didn't solve the problem, but you have given me the idea to solve it :).

Comment: @YeisonJ.Espinoza thank you very much, however I think that in this case you should upvote my answer, but not accept it, to not mislead another users, that my approach works.

Comment: @YeisonJ.Espinoza No problem :D I am glad my answer was useful in some way